# PHP - Use queue and cron job or directly process the request?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, queue

I'm working on a huge online sms system where users send messages from their user panel and these messages go to a mysql table named `messages_queue`.

Then, system fetches the queue rows and sends each message in a Cronjob. Of course it is important to send messages in a really fast way.

I'm thinking that isn't it better that I directly send messages (on user request) and don't use a queue? (sending messages needs to connect to an external API)

I found this when I was thinking about database I/O.
Isn't it a pressure on database?

**Edit/Answer:**

My question was a primarily opinion-based question. BTW for future use I will write what I did and what I got. On @bansi 's comment, I tried indexing my tables and this is what I saw:

This is what I was getting at start, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE parent="admin"
//response:OK
//Time: 3.581s
```

You know, 3.581 seconds for a query is a very long time. Then I tried to fetch exactly what I need:

```
SELECT uname FROM users WHERE parent="admin"
//response:OK
//Time: 1.02s
```

Okay, this was a little bit better, but still not what I want.
So, I tried this one:
Indexing queryable fields in database and using INDEX in query:

```
SELECT uname FROM users USE INDEX(parent) WHERE parent="admin"
//response:OK
//Time: 0.168s
```

Yes, it's what I want. Using `INDEX` and `specific needed fields` is about 30x faster and it's exactly what I need.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. In my opinion using a separate queue will be better as you can handle errors and connection delays easily. I don't think as of current technology state the sms sending can cause any database pressure, even if you are using a very outdated computer.

Comment: @bansi but in `ssh` I used `htop` and most of my queries were `SELECT * from messages_queue WHERE active=1 AND sendflag=0` and my average server load was about 3.0 while I'm using a good system as server. I think it's not a usual situation.

Comment: as far as I know cron minimum interval is 1 min and a query every minute is not going to overload the database. Note: you should finish your job ( or have some logic) before the next job starts, to avoid duplication.

Comment: @bansi yes, minimum interval is 1 min and maximum execution time is about 30 seconds, and yet server overloads and I don't know what is making this overload. Note: this is not only 1 cron job file, it's about 30 pages to send from multiple numbers and get message delivery state...

Comment: you should probably check the SMS sending API resource usage. BTW how many SMS/minute are you trying to send? Note: SMS sending has limitations (country dependent)

Comment: @bansi we have an unlimited API account but anyway we have 2000/min messages. I am almost sure that mysql queries are running so slow but don't know how to prevent this.

Comment: 2k/min SMS is going to be a bit trouble, you should think of multiple queues, select only what you can send from the database, most probably you are selecting too many rows from MySQL which is making it slow. BTW have you indexed the table?

Comment: @bansi I'm already using multiple queues for multiple SMS numbers. Anyway, thanks, they were good suggestions. I'll try indexing table and selecting rows more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the queue is being able to give a faster response to the user, so although the SMS doesn't get sent faster, the users will perceive the system as being faster because they click "send" and get a feedback immediately. You could maybe try to move your queue out of the database, to a dedicated queue processing system, like RabbitMQ.

Comment: That was a good answer, but it wasn't my answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I used MySQL to queue before, in time, if you don't clean the table, it will get really slow, you can use it but you always have the clean the executed rows...

But if you are looking for a real queue system, I would recommend RabbitMQ, it is easy and really amazing how much you can do with it.

Comment: I'm not so experienced in RabbitMQ and this is why I'm not working with that. (The system was developed based on MYSQL queue before, and it's another reason.) Anyway, I will take it really serious to have a clean table. Thanks.